# Location of compiled JSP in WepSphere Application Server

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

My application is deployed on websphere application server and I am getting error in jsp file. How to get compiled java code for that jsp in websphere. In development environment I am using jboss server and same code working fine.

Below is error log.

```
            [12/29/15 10:40:58:929 HKT] 0000013b LocalTranCoor E   WLTC0017E: Resources rolled back due to setRollbackOnly() being called. 
            [12/29/15 10:40:58:929 HKT] 0000013b webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/jsp/product/SIExpressionEditor.jsp]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException 
                    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseName(RequestUtils.java:353) 
                    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils.parseQueryString(RequestUtils.java:142) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseQueryStringList(SRTServletRequest.java:2377) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseParameters(SRTServletRequest.java:2353) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getParameterValues(SRTServletRequest.java:1876) 
                    at com.ibm._jsp._SIExpressionEditor._jspService(_SIExpressionEditor.java:118) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99) 
                    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) 
                    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122) 
                    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:216)
```

How to find

```
com.ibm._jsp._SIExpressionEditor._jspService(_SIExpressionEditor.java:118)
```

this line of compile code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `keepgenerated=true` option in the `ibm-web.ext.xml` file. The generated sources will be stored in the `Profile_Root/temp/node_name/server_name/EAR_App_Name/WAR_APP_Name/temp`.

For more details check:

- [Getting the generated Java source for a JSP file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232487)
- [Configuring JSP engine parameters](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jspengine.html?lang=en)
- [JSP engine configuration parameters - keepgenerated](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rweb_jspengine.html?lang=en)